# What are the reasons to use MonitoredTrainingSession vs Estimator in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I see many examples with either `MonitoredTrainingSession` or `tf.Estimator` as the training framework. However it's not clear why I would use one over the other. Both are configurable with `SessionRunHooks`. Both integrate with `tf.data.Dataset` iterators and can feed training/val datasets. I'm not sure what the benefits of one setup would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that `MonitoredTrainingSession` allows user to access Graph and Session objects, and training loop, while `Estimator` hides the details of graphs and sessions from the user, and generally, makes it easier to run training, especially, with `train_and_evaluate`, if you need to evaluate periodically.

`MonitoredTrainingSession` different from plain tf.Session() in a way that it handles variables initialization, setting up file writers and also incorporates functionality for distributed training.

`Estimator API`, on the other hand, is a high-level construct just like `Keras`. It's maybe used less in the examples because it was introduced later. It also allows to distribute training/evaluation with `DistibutedStrategy`, and it has several canned estimators which allow rapid prototyping.

In terms of model definition they are pretty equal, both allow to use either `keras.layers`, or define completely custom model from the ground up.  So, if, for whatever reason, you need to access graph construction or customize training loop, use `MonitoredTrainingSession`. If you just want to define model, train it, run validation and prediction without additional complexity and boilerplate code, use `Estimator`